# Displaying data in HTML using polymer

Tags: html, polymer

I have the following files:

**shop-categories.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<dom-module id="shop-category-data">

  <script>
  (function() {

    let val = "Country";

    class ShopCategoryData extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() { return 'shop-category-data'; }

      static get properties() { return {

        regionFilter: {
          type: String,
          value: val,
          notify: true
        }
        }
        }
    }

      customElements.define(ShopCategoryData.is, ShopCategoryData);

    })();

</script>

</dom-module>
```

Here is **shop-app.html** file

```
<link rel="import" href="shop-category-data.html">
<dom-module id="shop-app">

  <template>

    <shop-category-data regionFilter="{{regionFilter}}"></shop-category-data>

    <h1>HELLO</h1>
    <h1>{{regionFilter}}</h1>
  </template>

  <script>

       class ShopApp extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() { return 'shop-app'; }    

    }

    customElements.define(ShopApp.is, ShopApp);

  </script>

</dom-module>
```

I am trying to pass the value of `region` from shop-categories to shot-app. It is displaying `HELLO` but `country` is not getting displayed. I think these 2 lines should handle the display but they are not.

```
 <h1>HELLO</h1>
        <h1>{{regionFilter}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use *camelCase* property name (i.e. `regionFilter`) as an attribute, it has to be converted to *dash-case* version (i.e. `region-filter`).

**Change:**

`<shop-category-data regionFilter="{{regionFilter}}"></shop-category-data>`

**to:**

`<shop-category-data region-filter="{{regionFilter}}"></shop-category-data>`

Here is the working plnkr  link: http://plnkr.co/edit/A5FxAf?p=preview